# Debug device missing in VS2017 (Apache Cordova)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova

I am making a project in Visual Studio 2017 (Apache Cordova app).

I installed all the necessary accessories already, but I am missing the virtual device option debug.

Anyone know how can i get it there? I will post screens from sdk manager and vs :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use vscode as suggested by microsoft?

Comment: Bcs you can do this in vs2017 too. And i already had installed all the components

Comment: Yes that's true you can do it. Is there a down arrow next to "Install Android build tools..." where you can select a target?

Comment: Yeah there is. But if i clict it i only can simulate app in browser. not on virtual device. But when i simulate it in browser i dont get the apk file, that i need :/

Comment: If you just want an apk you can do `cordova build android --debug` or `cordova build android --release`

Comment: also if you have installed things it's probably a good idea to restart your ide to refresh the env.

Comment: Where can i put these comands please? I alreaddy restarted it. no change :/

Comment: You can execute this commands in your workfolder. Where your package.json and/or config.xml is

Comment: Also not working :/

Comment: Then your setup is incorrect

Comment: But, when i was debugging from VS2017 it was working. So i dont know what went wrong here. I cant debug any of my project like this. :/

Comment: That's the thing with the visual studio setup

Comment: What is the error message when you do `cordova build android`?

Comment: Like i said. I reinstalled whole vs and download all things again and nothing has changed. I will try again i guess

Comment: What i normally do is download android studio. And install all dependencies with android studio. Check that the you install android-sdk wihin a path with no whitespaces. c:/andoid-sdk. and don't use the visual studio manager for this. set the path to the newly installed sdk version. create an empty cordova project and test if you can build it with command line

Comment: Okay, ill try. Thx very much for your help 

Comment: no problem don't forget to update all your windows path variables

Comment: I wont :) txh very much